# Number of coefficients in a VAR($p$) model

Tags: vector-autoregression

How do you determine the dimension of a let's say VAR($p$) with 3 time series $(x,y,z)$ with a lag of $p=2$? From what I understand, the dimension depends of the number of time series and the lag size for the model.

Comment: How do you define the dimension of the model?

Comment: Often "dimensionality" of a linear model refers to the number of predictor variables. But it's not clear that that's what you're talking about; do you have more context?

Comment: the context is a Time Series, and what I'm trying to understand is the link between parameters of a VAR model and its dimension. e.g. i recorded that a VAR(1) has 12 parameters and is of dim 3.

Comment: A VAR model has $k+pk^2$ coefficients for lag order $p$ and $k$ time series. Is that what you need?

Comment: @ssdecontrol i think you are hitting the point. indeed I also recorded that a VAR (1) of 12 parameters is of dim 3. and 20 parameters of dim 4? does that make sense to you ? not so much to me because it doesn't add up... maybe my notes are of poor quality...

Comment: @RichardHardy can you describe the p operator in your expression ? i understand k stands for the lag size but not p ? is it the number of different series ? also, how to you use the nice formatting there, i'm new on this forum, i'm usually hanging on stackexchange^^

Comment: As I said above, $p$ is lag order (lag length) and $k$ is the number (dimension) of time series. Sorry that I used the notation opposite to how you did, I am just so used to the notation of the typical time series textbooks.

Comment: @RichardHardy ok, I see, so for let's say a simple VAR(1) with 3 TS, you would have a dimension of 12 ! That does indeed make sense with the rest :) that's exactly the kind of little expression i was looking for ! thank you very much ! so to answer my own question a VAR(2) with 3 time series has a dim of 3 + 2*3²=21 would be the answer :) thank you so much !!! 
PS: don't hesistate posting your answer, as official i don't see how to give you props myself^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the question is, what is the number of coefficients of a $k$-dimensional VAR($p$) model?

The number of coefficients in a VAR($p$) model for $k$ time series is $k+pk^2$.

- $k$ is the number of intercepts;
- each lag $p$ adds a $k \times k$ matrix of coefficients.